# The "Impedance" Equation

Tags: impedance, high-frequency, high-speed

[image]

In "Right the first time" by Lee W. Ritchey, he says "The impedance will be the same whether
the frequency of the EM energy is 1 MHz or 1 GHz. This holds true so long as none of the three variables changes with
frequency."

But clearly that equation has a dependence on \$ \omega \$ ? What's going on here?

Comment: I see *four* possible variables (R0, L0, G0, C0), of which *two* influence the frequency-dependent terms. Why does he say "three"? What is the context?

Comment: I've updated the picture to include more of what he says. I think you can access a pdf of the book here http://www.thehighspeeddesignbook.com/index.php

Comment: @VanGo  - What page of the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is downloadable from here: [Right First Time](http://www.thehighspeeddesignbook.com/index.php) and the relevant section of the book is pages 119 to 122.

In this book the author is specifically talking about PCB design and is making the reasonable assumption that \$ R_0 \$ and \$ G_0 \$ and negligible in comparison with the inductive and capacitive effects for frequencies of a few 100kHz and above.

This fits with my personal experience of PCB design and several authors have made the same assumption.

The statement \$ Z = \sqrt{\dfrac{R_0 + \text{j} \omega L_0}{G_0 + \text{j} \omega C_0}}\$ is false but at these frequencies the impedance varies very little with frequency and \$ Z = \sqrt{\dfrac{L_0}{C_0}}\$ is a very close approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at fairly standard cable used for telephones. It has a characteristic impedance that varies quite a lot in the audio range: -

[image]

And, this effect is as a direct result of the standard characteristic impedance equation for a transmission line. As frequency drops into the audio range, R starts to dominate over jwl and the impedance becomes: -

\$\sqrt{\dfrac{R}{j\omega C}}\$

As frequency lowers more the impedance tends to become: -

\$\sqrt{\dfrac{R}{G}}\$

And, at much higher frequencies, the characteristic impedance is the standard formula used by RF guys: -

\$\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$

It's also noteworthy that many sources refer to a transmission line as "distortionless" if the ratio R to G is the same as L to C. When this happens, the impedance is constant from DC to any frequency.